# Picture element used to provide multiple image formats and sizes always ends with fallback

Tags: html, css

I have a VueJS template which roughly approximates HTML but looks like this:

```html
<picture>
  <source type="image/avif" :scrset="avif" />
  <source type="image/webp" :scrset="webp" />
  <source type="image/jpg" :scrset="jpg" />

  <img class="p-image" :src="fallback" :alt="alt" v-bind="$attrs" />
</picture>
```

In chrome this is rendered as:
[image: browser source]

On visual inspection this *looks right* to me. Sadly it's always using the fallback image of `music-768.jpg`. Am I missing something? I want to prefer AVIF where the browser supports it, then WEBP and finally JPG.

Answer (score 0):

This was just the case of a typo!

- `scrset` is `scrSet`